# How do I swap a crafted Item for another one (in bedrock edition)?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am making an adventure map and am making it so that you craft a piece of tnt that should be placed on an observer. Though, when it is crafted it can't be placed on anything.
I have tried several times with different commands but none seem to work.

```
/replaceitem entity @p [name=tnt]slot.weapon.mainhand 1 tnt 1 0 {"minecraft:can_place_on":{"blocks":["observer"]}}
```

This is one command i've tried several times. It looks promising but says that "no targets matched selector". Even if the "[name=tnt]" is swapped by "[name=!tnt]" (that should make it so that everything exept tnt changes) the tnt changes.

I would be greatful if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your command is trying to do is replace the nearest player whose player name is `tnt`'s mainhand slot. Because your Minecraft username isn't `tnt`, it is not finding you.

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to detect an item in a specific item slot in Minecraft Bedrock. You can, however, run `/clear @p tnt -1 1` to clear a TNT from a player, and test whether it succeeds using a conditional chain command block.

Comment: can you give an example for that chained block.Like, how does it detect the succeded clearing?

Comment: yes. The green command blocks

Comment: so:
impulse command block: unconditional, always active "clear @p tnt -1 1" >
> chain command block: conditional, always active "give @p "special tnt""

Comment: OMG. It worked, first it didnt because the arrow wasnt pointing to the chain block. But now it works, Thank you!

Comment: Btw, can the "impulse command block" be a repeat one? or do i have to make a redstone clock that runs into it?